# Is there a way to use a static void declared in .cpp in another .cpp in the same project

Tags: c++

I have a static function that is declared in .cpp function that I can't declare in the header because it should not be visible. 
I want to re-use it in another .cpp in the same project.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Nope, by making it `static` it's visible only in the [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (roughly source file with all header files included) the function was defined in.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself - therefore that is the answer

Comment: Should not be visible to whom?

Comment: Maybe you should rethink your design? Or use namespaces to separate functions?

Comment: That's not my design so I can't just change it without solid reason to. I just wasn't sure that it can't be done. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Put it in a separated header (eventually in a hidden folder) and include that in the two source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions here:

1. Is this possible?
2. is this a good idea?

Regarding the first question, check out the [`extern` keyword](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/). If you don't use `static` on the function, then, in a different source file, you can "re-declare" it using the `extern` keyword, and use it.

Regarding the second question, there are probably better options, such as a "detail" or "implementation" namespace (see [some thoughts on best practices for namespaces](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50120/best-practices-for-using-namespaces-in-c)). Using well-established conventions, you can convey that some declaration is used for implementation only, and is not really part of the interface.